# How to remove the HTML tags while get Angular inhalt {{ Description }} over API

Tags: angular, api

I get information over API useing Angular.

All Fields I get without Problem, only the description appears with HTML tags.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
  </div>
    <p class="e2e-inner-html-interpolated"> {{ current_seminar.seminarDescription}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get the outout with HTML tags so:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6fCa.png)

is there any way to remove the <!DOCTYPE html and all tags using Angular?
Or it's a problem with sending the description text over API?

I tried use `[innerHTML]`:

```
<p class="e2e-inner-html-bound" [innerHTML]="current_seminar.seminarDescription"></p>
```

But it didn't help.

Comment: I would say this is an API problem. It appears that an entire HTML document is being sent instead of just the description text. To remove the HTML tags and display only the information you want, you would need a custom parser.

Comment: @riorudo thanks for your answer, could you tell me how can I user a custom parser? it can be writte in my HTML file?

Comment: This is certainly not easy. You need to know exactly what your answer is and use JavaScript to extract the information you want. I wouldn't recommend doing that. Rather customize your api and return a json with the information you need.